# change 2d array by a "dictionary translation" in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following 2d array `[[2,3,4],[4,4,2]` and the following dictionary `{2:7,3:5,4:6}` 
I would like somehow to transform the array using the dictionary, i.e. have as an output the following result:

```
[[7,5,6],[6,6,7]]
```

Is there a simple (maybe built-in function) to do so?

Comment: I don't think there is an inbuilt function to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Tip to get a good answer: Please do add your previously written code to the question. Also, you missed a closing bracket in `[[2,3,4],[4,4,2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [np.vectorize()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
x = np.array([[2,3,4],[4,4,2]])
y = {2:7,3:5,4:6}
np.vectorize(y.get)(x)

array([[7, 5, 6],
       [6, 6, 7]])
```